React Native Expo Local Images Not Showing
I'm simply tying to display a local image in my react native expo project and it refuses to work. I get no errors, its just not there. I understand this question has been asked before, but I can't find an answer that works or that uses the recent versions of the packages.
my packages:
"expo": "^51.0.9",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.1",
"@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.2.1",
"@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
"expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
"expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
"expo-router": "~3.5.15",
"expo-secure-store": "~13.0.1",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
"react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
"react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
"expo-image": "~1.12.9",
"expo-asset": "~10.0.6"

If I change the image source path, I then get an error saying it can't find the image, so by that logic if it is not complaining about the current path, then it can see the file, its just not showing it. I tried importing "Image" from react-native and expo-image, neither worked (I'm ok with using either I really don't care I just want one to work). Finally I have tried swapping in other pictures to see if that picture was corrupt or something but no luck, the below setup won't show any pictures. I'd appreciate any help. I am using the expo go app to scan the terminal qr code and test on my iPhone. Here is my code:


import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

export default function Full() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Title</Text>
            <Image
                source={require('../../assets/icon.png')}
                width={50}
                height={50}
                style={styles.image}
            />
            <Text>Subtitle</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(30, 41, 59)',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: 200,
        height: 200
    },
    image: {
        width: 50,
        height: 50
    },
});



Edit: Screen shot after attempting @michael-bahl suggestion


Did you restart the packager, did you start  reset cache npm start —reset-cache or watch watch-del-all

I just tried npm start --reset-cache expo start --reset-cache and expo start -c. They all packaged and started running with no errors, but still no image

Is the text <Text>Title</Text> visible? Add backgroundColor: ‘#ff0000’, flex:0 to  styles.image

is ../../assets/icon.png outside of src ?

@MichaelBahl I tried your changes and posted a screenshot of the result

@MichaelBahl yes the Title text is visible

@Amir-Mousavi I am using expo file based routing, I don't have a src folder. The image is at /assets/icon.png and the "full" component trying to use the image is at /ui/logo/full/js

That last path was a typo, meant: /ui/logo.js

I figured it out while creating a snack per @Rahmon-Haroon request. The snack editor complained about some compatibility issues between my packages and suggested I bump one. Which I did locally and then on the rerun expo prompted me to bump a few more. I did and now the image is appearing. Thank goodness. Thank you everyone for your help.
Here is the final working snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@tristan-neateworks/react-native-expo-local-images-not-showing
And here are my final packages:
"expo": "^51.0.10",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.1",
"@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.2.1",
"@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
"expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
"expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
"expo-router": "~3.5.14",
"expo-secure-store": "~13.0.1",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
"react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
"react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
"expo-image": "~1.12.10",
"expo-asset": "~10.0.7"


Make sure your path is correct. Mostly the path you given is wrong. Try as below


import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

const imagePath = require("./assets/snack-icon.png");

export default function Full() {
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Title</Text>
        <Image
            source={imagePath}
            width={50}
            height={50}
            style={styles.image}
        />
        <Text>Subtitle</Text>
    </View>
);
};

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
  flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
},
image: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50
},
});




Thank you for your reply, but it appears pulling out the image path to its own variable didn't have any affect

I'm not sure if its the wrong path. As is, it runs without errors, however if I change the path to a known missing file, it complains and errors out saying the file doesn't exist. Along that logic I think it can see the current file, its just not displaying it

can you try with some other image and replace the path @TristanNeate
or please share a expo snack so we can identify the actual issue here

thank you for the snack suggestion, it led to the solution

Incase someone else bumps into this - I literally followed all advice everywhere having ran into this issue after running an expo prebuild, with no images showing afterwards, and no errors.
I reverted plugin changes, reverted app changes, re-installed earlier plugin versions, deleted the expo app on the simulator, closed and re-opened the simulator, cleared app caches, added preloading with expo-image package, none of it worked.
What solved it here was deleting the node_modules folder and re-installing all packages fresh.

Still doesn't work for me.
In SDK52, I'm able to remove expo-image package entirely and just use Image from react-native as the solution.
